# How to do something based on CSS variable content?

Tags: css, css-variables

Let's say I have a CSS variable:

```
div {
  --test: "hey"
}
```

And I would like to check what is inside this variable and do something based on this.

For example:

```
if var(--test) == "Hi":
  margin-left: 1rem;
else:
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to check what is inside this variable and do something based on this.

Yes, you can check the value of a **CSS Custom Property** natively using:

```
window.getComputedStyle(myDiv).getPropertyValue('--test')
```

Once you know the value of `--test`, you can either update one (or several) properties:

- `myDiv.style.setProperty('padding-bottom', '1rem');`

or you can add a class which updates one property (or any number of properties) of `myDiv`:

- `myDiv.classList.add('increaseBottomPadding');`

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

divs.forEach((div) => {

  let testValue = window.getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue('--test');
  
  switch (testValue) {
    case ('rainbow1') : div.classList.add('background1'); break;
    case ('rainbow2') : div.classList.add('background2'); break;
    case ('rainbow3') : div.classList.add('background3'); break;
    case ('rainbow4') : div.classList.add('background4'); break;
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border: 8px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.div1 {
  --test: rainbow1;
}

.div2 {
  --test: rainbow2;
}

.div3 {
  --test: rainbow3;
}

.div4 {
  --test: rainbow4;
}

.background1 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}


.background2 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 127, 0);
}


.background3 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}


.background4 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 127, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
<div class="div4"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

natively isn't possible, but with a css compiler you can!

I suggest you use `SASS/SCSS` for this:

> https://sass-lang.com/ (is a CSS compiler, that let you write CSS in a comfortable way, then compile it (translating it) to a CSS native)

for using IF/ELSE see these docs https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if

[image]

Comment: How can i use this with css variables?

Comment: @Hostek yes, but the syntax is different. a sass variable is `$name` an in CSS native was `--name`